# Comma placement in a relative clause example

Tags: comma, relative-clause

An example from [the Dartmouth page on relative clauses](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~german/Grammatik/RelativeClauses/relatives.html):

> Was mich ärgert, ist, dass sie sich nicht entschuldigt hat.

Why is there a comma before the 'ist'? The comma before 'dass' makes sense (since it's the start of a relative clause), but I would think that 'ist' is part of the first clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence has the simple base structure

> [subject] ist [object]. → verb is `ist`

The object is the clause

> , dass sie sich nicht entschuldigt hat → verb is `sich entschuldigt haben`

The subject is the clause

> Was mich ärgert, → verb is `ärgern`

All clauses need to be split from the main clause by commas, also the first one ending on `ärgert`.

Answer (score 5):

The first comma denotes the end of a dependent clause (I think it is called "open relative clause"). I'll rearrange the parts

> Das, was mich ärgert, ist, dass sie...

Answer (score 1):

I just want to mention a rule of thumb:

> Separate any clauses that contain a **conjugated verb** from each other with a comma.

In your example there are three conjugated verbs: "ärgert", "ist" and "hat". Hence, you need two commas.

Note, I'm not saying that you should blindly set a bunch of commas whenever you see two or more conjugated verbs. For instance, a comma may be replaced with a conjunction and then it'd be wrong to use a comma.